# How do I get all possible item combinations from two tables when some items have the same ID value?

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I am self-teaching Python and have encountered a problem. Let’s  say I have two csv tables, listing projects with the programming languages and frameworks they use:

```
| ProjectID | ProgrammingLanguageID |
| --------- | --------------------- |
| 1         | 32                    |
| 1         | 27                    |
| 3         | 8                     |
```

And:

```
| ProjectID | FrameworkID           |
| --------- | --------------------- |
| 1         | 3                     |
| 1         | 7                     |
| 2         | 5                     |
```

Expected language-framework combinations e.g. for ProjectID 1 would be:

```
(p32, f3)
```

```
(p32, f7)
```

```
(p27, f3)
```

```
(p27, f7)
```

How do I get all the possible combinations for every project?

I think itertools could solve the problem but I have no idea how to include the project IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read both cdv as pandas dataframes and then join the FrameworkID to the ProgrammingLanguageID using ProjectID as your key.
Let's say your first df is called languages and the second frameworks, than the following could work

```
result = languages.merge(frameworks, on="ProjectID", how="outer")

# output
ProjectID   ProgrammingLanguageID   FrameworkID
1           32.0                    3.0
1           32.0                    7.0
1           27.0                    3.0
1           27.0                    7.0
3           8.0                     NaN
2           NaN                     5.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I used full outer join for an overview of the data. But how should I go about to get all the possible pairs? Right now there are records with only one language and multiple frameworks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. with the join you see all combinations don't you? I edited my answer to include outer join and the output

Comment: Sorry, the brainfog got the better of me. Using outer join I was able to generate all possible combinations. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Would you mark the questions as solved